# Add Key for list of multiple object ~ dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   final uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h");
    final res = await http.get(uri);
    var data = (jsonDecode(res.body)).toList();



    var name = [
      "Datetime",
      "Open",
      "High",
      "Low",
      "Close",
      "Volume",
      "Close time",
      "Quote",
      "Number of trades",
      "taker buy",
      "taker buy quote",
      "ignore"
    ];

    var output = [
      for (var d in data) Map<String, String>.fromIterable(name,value: d)
    ];
    print(output);
```

Try:

```
var output = Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterables(name, data);
```

**Error:
Uncaught Error: Invalid argument(s): Iterables do not have same length.**

**Error 2:
Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => String)?'**

*Need output like below list:*

```
   [ {Open time: 1650409200000, Open: 41395.38000000, High: 41539.90000000, Low: 41395.38000000, Close: 41493.18000000, Volume: 850.49595000, Close time: 1650412799999, Quote asset volume: 35269640.77746520, Number of trades: 22594, Taker buy base asset volume: 396.50601000, Taker buy quote asset volume: 16441271.67871090, Ignore: 0},
    {Open time: 1650412800000, Open: 41493.19000000, High: 41541.23000000, Low: 41250.26000000, Close: 41295.37000000, Volume: 1226.31947000, Close time: 1650416399999, Quote asset volume: 50763275.81698850, Number of trades: 35252, Taker buy base asset volume: 508.56187000, Taker buy quote asset volume: 21051672.90479120, Ignore: 0}]
```

i'am using for method for each object but it dose not return the list value.

Comment: `var output = [Map.fromIterables(name, data[0]), Map.fromIterables(name, data[1])];`.  More generally: `var output = [for (var d in data) Map.fromIterables(name, d)];`.

Comment: thanks @jamesdlin

For method works fine...!!!

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin This one work for sample given 2 datas but i have 500 data like this it's not working for this.... 
Data source : https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h

Comment: It should work regardless of the number of entries in `data` *as long as each entry has the same length as `name`*.  If it's not working (what error?), then that one of your entries is malformed.

Comment: i'm sure about all the entries in data  same length. but get below error

ERROR:
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => String)?'

Comment: @jamesdlin Code updated

Comment: You're using `Map<String, String>.fromIterable`, which is wrong because: 1. [`Map.fromIterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html) is a different constructor than [`Map.fromIterables`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterables.html) (note that the latter is plural!). 2. `Map<String, String>` is wrong because your values are not all `String`s.  It should be `Map<String, dynamic>` (or you should just omit the explicit types and let the types be inferred).

Comment: yes it's correct now it's worked with Map.fromIterables thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't notice that what you're doing is wrong

Map.fromIterables takes two lists (In your case, a String list and a dynamic list), and makes the first list's values the map's keys, and the second list's values the map's values.

But what you're saying to dart by

```
 Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterables(name, data);
```

Is actually:
"Hey I have a String list, and a list with two lists, could you make it a Map please?"

So more simply, do the following:

```
//You make a list out of data[0] and data[1]
var output = [Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterables(name, data[0]), Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterables(name, data[1])];
```

Or, if data's length is variable you could use:

```
var output = [for(var d in data) Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterables(name, d)];
//For each element in data you parse the data
```

Comment: Hi,

This one work for sample given 2 datas but i have 500 data like this it's not working for this.... 

Data source : https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you have more than 2 entries, you have to use the second solution :)